# Best text miner to use with python

Tags: python

I want to use a easy-to-use text miner with my python code. I will be mainly using the classification algorithms - Naive Bayes, KNN and such. 
Please let me know what's the best option here - Weka? NLTK? SVM? or something else?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go with NLTK since it's written in Python